# How to save Remote Desktop Connection (vinagre) names for Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, remote-desktop

Remote Desktop Client comes already installed in Ubuntu 11.10 (named as `vinagre`). It's a nice and one stop application for accessing remote machines using `SSH, VNC, RDP` (typically to windows machines).

However, I am not able to see any option for **saving the names for the connections**. Everytime, I have to provide the machine name, username, password etc. details ? Is there any add-on to enable saving the details of a connection ?

For now, I have installed "remmina" (`sudo apt-get install remmina`) client, which has all these facilities. However, I am wondering why such trivial facility is not there in `vinagre` Remote Desktop ?